# How to call a function inside a function that is created in seperate python files?

Tags: function, variables, variable-assignment, nameerror, defined

I have written the two functions below in the same python file. If I print the answer function it returns the answer of 7 which is expected.

The second function is calling the first function to get the answer.

If I create two python files as below and run it there is an error NameError: name 'math' is not defined.

Why am I not able to create the function that is required to run answer() in the second python file?

I have tried referencing math = 0 to give it a starting variable. My goal is to be able to build functions that I can import into the main python file where that function uses functions created in the main file. The two files are p1.py and p2.py

```
def math(x,y):
    answer = x + y
    return answer

def answer():
    answer = math(5,2)
    return answer

print(answer())

# Returns the answer of 7
```

```
def answer():
    answer = math(5,2)
    return answer
```

```
import p1

def math(x,y):
    answer = x + y
    return answer

print(answer())


# Returns NameError: name 'math' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to make it work, you can make `answer` take a function as an argument:

```
def answer(math):
    answer = math(5,2)
    return answer
```

and call it with `answer(math)`, or you could import it in p1.py by adding `from p2 import math`.